# How to copy data from Excel and Paste into Project using a VBA Code?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

Does anyone know how to copy data from Excel and Paste into Project using a VBA Code. I have a large Excel document that I want the Macro to go through, to pull the necessary tasks, and then paste the Task Names into MS Project.

Below is the code that I have tried to run. I have removed the actual reference object files for privacy reasons.

```
Sub CopyPaste2()
' Macro CopyPaste2



Dim EObject As Object
Set EObject = GetObject("C:Excel_File_Name")

Dim Pro As Project
Set Pro = GetObject("C:Project_File_Name")

Dim t As Task

EObject.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A6").Copy
Pro.View(GanttChart).FieldName (TaskName)

End Sub
```

The line where it is called out to paste into Project, an Error appears:
"Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean 'paste' the task names (in which case you should include the line that is doing the 'pasting') or 'create new' tasks? Either way, can you confirm the exact line on which the error occurs (ie the line highlighted, normally in yellow, when your code stops)?

Comment: @JohnM Yep I am trying to 'paste' the task names. The exact line on which the error occurs is "Pro.View(GanttChart).FieldName(TaskName)"

Comment: Juls, Answer, "yes". You get an error on that line because there is no "FieldName" property for a view object. It appears you are copying a column of names on an Excel Worksheet. You need to use the SelectColumn Method followed by an EditPaste statement. As a side comment, you have posted a couple of questions on this forum but I have yet to see any feedback from you or any responses accepted as the answer.